# Error user input PLS-00201: identifier 'ISS' must be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql

Why do I get this error? If the variable declaration is the same type as the column shouldn't this work. The nursing_unit_id is a varchar2(10). It worked like this for me when the ID was a NUMBER;

Error I get: 
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 13, column 13:
PLS-00201: identifier 'ISS' must be declared

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
v_unit ADMISSIONS.NURSING_UNIT_ID%TYPE := &v_unit;
v_admissions ADMISSIONS%ROWTYPE;

CURSOR c_admissions IS
  SELECT *
  INTO v_admissions
  FROM ADMISSIONS
  WHERE NURSING_UNIT_ID = v_unit;

BEGIN
  FOR r_admissions IN c_admissions
  LOOP  
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r_admissions );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: ISS is the user input I enter for the nursing_unit_id

Comment: That is not the correct CURSOR syntax.  You declare the cursor, then after the BEGIN you OPEN, FETCH and CLOSE the cursor.  Also, give your bind variable (&v_unit) a different name to your valriable.  Also, I don't think you can pass a ROWTYPE variable to DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line() - it takes a text argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `nursing_unit_id` is `varchar2(10)` and you've defined the substitution variable `&v_unit` as `ISS`, then you have to enclose the reference to the substitution variable in quotes, to make it a string:

```
v_unit ADMISSIONS.NURSING_UNIT_ID%TYPE := '&v_unit';
```

If you run your code in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer with `set verify on`, you'll see the before and after values for that substitution, which would show it it trying to to do:

```
v_unit ADMISSIONS.NURSING_UNIT_ID%TYPE := ISS;
```

instead of what you'd get with it quoted:

```
v_unit ADMISSIONS.NURSING_UNIT_ID%TYPE := 'ISS';
```

You will still get other errors; the next one is:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'

You've defined `v_admissions` as a row type, which means it's a record. You can't write a whole record out in one go with `dbms_output`, you have to refer to each field separately, e.g. (using your amended code, where `r_admissions is also implicitly of that same row type):

```
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r_admissions.nursing_unit_id);
```

Having an `into` clause in the cursor definition isn't useful; it isn't actually populated, so you can remove that clause and the `v_admissions` variable declaration. You don't really need the `v_unit` local variable either, you can use the substitution variable directly; and there are various cursor forms you can use, such as:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
BEGIN 
  FOR r_admissions IN (
    SELECT *
    FROM ADMISSIONS
    WHERE NURSING_UNIT_ID = '&v_unit'
  )
  LOOP  
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r_admissions.nursing_unit_id);
    -- and anything else you want to do with that row's data
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```